# npm install: Unsupported platform warning issue

Tags: npm-install, npm-start

When I run `npm install` command, it shows following warning

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.12 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.12: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

audited 18093 packages in 9.83s

36 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Comment: This is a warning, right? What issue are you facing due to this warning?

Comment: I missed your comment on time. In my case, my OS is windows, so there is no problem. I updated my answer as below.

Comment: any update about it?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding and searching.
If you work on Windows OS, don't need to pay attention.
Because that is only for Mac OS. also NPM will not help install it into windows OS.

[NPM fsevent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsevents)
This module for MAC OS.

> The FSEvents API in MacOS allows applications to register for notifications of changes to a given directory tree

Comment: "Unsupported platform: win32 ia32 LE" showed for me while running `npm install`, possibly because my OS is 64bits and node binary was 32bits. I had to completely remove node.js 32 bits (node-v18.12.1-x86.msi) from Windows and install this time its 64 bits version (node-v18.12.1-x64.msi). Then grab a coffee, sit, read the news and wait the endless install of Chocolatey in PowerShell  current version now is v18.12.1

Comment: Actually I have no idea about your situation, but I suggest is, should restart OS after install node even if you are using NVM. Do not use powershell for npm command because of  powershell not work well sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Run This Command  `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`